# Как парсить видео с сайтов

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

В src указана ссылка типа blob:https://www.site.com/...
Как можно загрузить такое видео у себя на сайте, НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЙТЕ СТОРОННИЕ СОФТЫ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА.

Comment: Я имею введу получить реальную ссылку, к примеру что бы использовать в теге video?

Answer (score 3):

URL-адрес, созданный из BLOB-объекта JavaScript, нельзя преобразовать в «обычный» URL-адрес.

BLOB-URL-адрес не относится к данным, существующим на сервере, он относится к определенной части данных (из общего целого), которую ваш браузер **в данный момент** хранит в памяти, **для текущей страницы**. И эта текущая часть практически не доступна на других страницах, не доступна в других браузерах и не доступна с других компьютеров.

Следовательно, если вы хотите получить обычный URL-адрес, вам придется сформировать и отправить исходный запрос из браузера на сервер, и сервер вернет вам обычный файл. Однако на многих медиа-серверах такой запрос зависит от текущей сессии, и может иметь механизмы защиты от размещения контента на сторонних сайтах.

Comment: А как можно послать такой запрос ?

Comment: Зависит от конкретного сайта, у всех по разному...